# How to set a transparent background for an AVVideoComposition?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, transparent, background-color, avcomposition

**Update** - I've added a 50 reputation bounty for answering this question!

I have an application that needs to put together some videos and photos to create a movie out of them. I am using AVMutableComposition for that. To be able to instruct it how the videos get composed I have to use an AVMutableVideoComposition. This thing has a property called `backgroundColor` and Apple Documentation says:

> Only solid BGRA colors are supported; patterns and other supported
>   colors are ignored. If the rendered pixel buffer does not have alpha,
>   the alpha value of the background color is ignored.

What I understand from this is that there is a way to add alpha channel to the backgroundColor  but I just don't understand how. What does `If the rendered pixel buffer does not have alpha, the alpha value of the background color is ignored.` mean? And how I can add such thing?

If I just do `myVideoCompositionInstruction.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0] CGColor];` it just doesn't work - the background stays white and doesn't go transparent.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? I really need this and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried myVideoCompositionInstruction.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]?

Comment: Yup - doesn't do it either :(

Comment: How about [UIColor redColor].CGColor?  Does it turn red? This will at least eliminate the possibility of you not using the property correctly.

Comment: It does turn red or any other color I apply to it. It just doesn't go transparent whatever I do to it :(

Comment: More code would help. Maybe you can strip it down to something extremely basic and post it?

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: I don't think I ever managed to fix this. It's been so long ago I don't really remember but I think I just took another approach and never had to deal with it anymore...

Comment: The paradox here is H.264 video doesn't support alpha channel so Apple intentionally disabled alpha channel support for background color. I tried everything but could never get alpha channel working on background color.

Answer (score 2):

In Apple's documentation for `AVVideoCompositionInstruction` the property you want to set, `backgroundColor`, is of type `CGColorRef`.

My bet is, because you are setting `backgroundColor` with **UIColor** and only then getting the value of it through the **CGColor** property, for some reason the alpha value doesn't get passed into a CGColorRef object. You know the white value gets passed because the default color is black.

UIColor has some limitations. I suggest you read the following [article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components.ars). Take particular notice of the section **"The problems with UIColor"** of the article.

I'm guessing the best solution for your problem is defining `backgroundColor` with **CGColor** directly (use [CGColorCreate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html), for instance), instead of UIColor.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try this as soon as I get to the office tomorrow and I'll let you know if this works...

Comment: I did this 

`CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        float transparentWhite[] = { 1, 1, 1, 0 };
        CGColorRef backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, transparentWhite);
        
        _videoInstruction.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;`

and it still doesn't work...

Comment: I tried this, the white color gets visible with this method but the alpha is ignored, even if I set opacity for the rendered pixel buffer. Any ideas why this could happen and any ways to workaround ?